# S3 Bucket Notifications on Multiple Criteria

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am running a continuous code deployment with Jenkins that will automatically compile and upload binaries to S3 in parallel for multiple targets.

The final step in my deployment mechanism is to detect that all the binaries for a particular build has been uploaded, and then deploy them together.

S3 has event notifications that can trigger when objects have been pushed, but do they have anything more sophisticated that can trigger when multiple objects have been pushed?

Example:

1. Build machine on Windows uploads binary to S3.
2. Build machine on OS X uploads binary to S3.
3. S3 detects that both binaries are now uploaded and triggers an event.
4. Build machine takes both binaries and releases them together.

Right now the only solution I can think of is to set up AWS Lambda and have the event handler manually check for the existence of the other binary, which may not even be feasible if S3 has special race conditions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. There is no mechanism that would let you trigger an action when all three objects are uploaded. There is no conditional notification, just simple events.

But you can use something else. Create a `DynamoDB` table for the build records and create a row there when your build is successful from any build machine, before you upload any files. Now for each build, create a separate attribute on the row. Have `S3` publish a notification to your `Lambda` and have your `Lambda` lookup and update this row and when all your attributes are in desired state, you can have this `Lambda` do the release.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 is a "base" system upon which many things can be built (eg DropBox!). As such, the functionality of Amazon S3 is limited (but very scalable and reliable).

Thus, you'll have to build your own logic on top of Amazon S3 to implement your desired solution.

One option would be to trigger an AWS Lambda function when an object is created. This Lambda function could then implement any logic you desire, such as your step #3.